# Usar NULL en variable/parámetro para indicar que no usaremos dicho filtro

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta con varias condiciones en la clausula **where** y tengo un parámetro que puede ser **null** y tiene registros. En este caso **@codigo** puede tener valor o puede ser **null**. Cuando aplico `@codigo is null or codigo = @codigo` las demás condiciones no se cumplen y me lista todos los productos de cualquier tipo, de todas las tiendas por ejemplo.

```
   select * 
          from tb_producto 
          where id_tipoproducto = @tipo 
                and id_tienda = @id_tienda 
                and codigo_producto = @codigo
```

Comment: Si entiendo, si codigo es null no quieres que afecta la consulta?

Comment: Freddy no está claro lo que preguntas, puedes editar tu consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras hacer con `@codigo` cuando éste sea NULL.

Si es una forma de indicar -> "No filtramos por este dato" puedes hacer esto:

```
select * 
      from tb_producto 
      where id_tipoproducto = @tipo 
            and id_tienda = @id_tienda 
            and (@codigo IS NULL OR codigo_producto = @codigo)
```

Ahora si en la tabla efectivamente hay valores de codigo_producto = NULL y queremos recuperarlos:

```
select * 
      from tb_producto 
      where id_tipoproducto = @tipo 
            and id_tienda = @id_tienda 
            and ((@codigo IS NULL AND codigo_producto IS NULL)
                  OR
                  (codigo_producto = @codigo)
                )
```

Comment: Patricio, se cumple cuando @codigo es null pero cuando tiene valor no me lista nada...

Comment: Yo revisaría @codigo que el valor sea del mismo tipo que codigo_producto, por ahora no alcanzo a ver ningún problema en el código que te pasé. Que motor de base de datos usas?

Comment: Haciendo unos reajustes si obtengo el resultado que buscaba, lo que pasa es que es un codigo de ejemplo lo real tiene varios inner join y faltaba especificar el parametro correcto, pero entendiste la idea. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas buscando esto:

```
select * 
from tb_producto 
where id_tipoproducto = @tipo 
and id_tienda = @id_tienda 
and codigo_producto = ISNULL(@codigo, codigo_producto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta debe quedar así:

```
select * 
  from tb_producto 
 where id_tipoproducto = @tipo 
       and id_tienda = @id_tienda 
       and (@codigo is null or codigo_producto = @codigo)
```

En este caso primero se evalúa si `@codigo` es un valor nulo (no si `@codigo = NULL` que es diferente) y si no es así, entonces prosigue con el otro lado del `or`.