# Como puedo mostrar todos los campos si los datos de entrada están vacías en Sql?

Tags: sql

He creado esta tabla para hacer pruebas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que si los datos de entrada que son 2 al ejecutar el procedimiento me muestren todos

```
> create procedure Sp_prueba3 @Faini int, @Fafin int as begin select *
> from dedito where fff>=@Faini and fff<=@Fafin end
```

Comment: si estan vacias que cosas?

Comment: si están vacías los datos de entrada mostrar todos

Comment: No queda claro (al menos para mi) que motor estas utilizando, Ms SQL Server?
De todos modos, porque deben ser vacias? Faini=-1 y Fafin=1e100 no es lo mismo?

Comment: No voy a marcarla como duplicada pero es muy parecida a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81715/valores-nulos-en-parametros-dentro-de-la-clausula-where-en-sql/81718#81718

Answer (score 3):

Lo que veo es que tienes un store procedure el cual recibe unos parametros para filtrar.
Ahora bajo esa premisa, lo que buscas es; si recibo los parametros hago una busqueda con ellos, caso contrario no filtro.

De estar en los cierto, lo que necesitarías dentro del store procedure es generar un query para ambos escenarios:

```
create procedure Sp_prueba3 @Faini int, @Fafin int 
as begin

    if @Faini != 0 and @Fafin != 0
        begin
            select*
            from dedito 
            where fff >= @Faini and fff <= @Fafin  --  Filtramos
        end
    else
        select*
        from dedito  --  No filtramos
end
```

Espero mi respuesta te ayude o te guíe a dar con una solución. Saludos.

Comment: +1 Justo iba a colocar una respuesta similar. Creo que esto es lo que busca el OP.

Comment: Esperemos que ello sea, es lo que entendí.